# Must declare the scalar variable "@loginName"

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to login using `LoginID` and `Password` as user name and password respectively, however I'm getting an exception:

> Must declare the scalar variable “@loginName”

```
protected void SignInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int customerId = 0;
    int loginName = Convert.ToInt32(LoginTextBox.Text);
    string password = PasswordTextBox.Text;
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;
    command.CommandText = "Select CustomerID from Customers where LoginID= @loginName and Password= @password";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", loginName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerId);
    reader = DbUtility.GetDataReader(command);

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();
        customerId = reader.GetInt32(0);
        Session["CustomerID"] = customerId;
        Response.Redirect("ListCategories.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        MessegeLabel.Text = "User Name or Password Incorrect";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are try and then... what happens? Do you get an error? Does it not compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some SQL there which includes the parameter `@loginName`. You never provide that parameter; you provide an unused parameter called `@LoginID` instead (along with an unused `@CustomerID` also, for some reason).

It's telling you that it needs you to provide all the parameters your SQL snippet uses.

```
command.CommandText = "Select CustomerID from Customers where LoginID= @loginName and Password= @password";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", loginName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customerId);
```

So provide it:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginName", loginName);
```